# String value wrongly converted to datetime using vb.net

Tags: vb.net, parsing, datetime

So I have this datetime value of 9.3.2016 18:56:12, by using datetime.parse, I can get the values but instead of getting '3' as the month, it takes '9' as month and '3' as day which is incorrect.

```
dim d1 as string = "9.3.2016 18:56:12"
dim d2 as datetime = datetime.parse(d1, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

I don't want to use datetime.parseExact because I'm having more than 1 value in the database.

Please help :( thank you!

Comment: if you don't want to use `ParseExact` you'll need a culture where dates are in the format `DD.MM.YYYY`, looks French to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you current culture appears to interpret dates in the way you expect you could simply do this,

```
Dim dateString = "9.3.2016 18:56:12"
Dim dateValue = DateTime.Parse(dateString)
```

By not specifying the `InvariantCulture`, you instruct `DateTime.Parse` to use the current culture which, in your case, interprets the date string correctly.

Answer (score -1):

Sorry I've got the solution.

```
dim d2 as datetime = convert.todatetime(d1)
```

Comment: This only works because you current culture interprets dates in the way you expect.

Comment: There is nothing special per se, about `Convert.ToDateTime`.